# Ar Anchor in Unity Hub

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, vuforia

I am trying to build a simple ar model which just overlays a plane over an image target. But for a few days I get this warnings

1.Packages\package\Vuforia\Scripts\Internal\ARFoundationIntegration\ARFoundationFacade.cs(268,26): warning CS0618: 'ARAnchorManager.AddAnchor(Pose)' is obsolete: 'Add an anchor using AddComponent(). (2020-10-06)'

2.Packages\package\Vuforia\Scripts\Internal\ARFoundationIntegration\ARFoundationFacade.cs(298,17): warning CS0618: 'ARAnchorManager.RemoveAnchor(ARAnchor)' is obsolete: 'Call Destroy() on the ARAnchor component to remove it. (2020-10-06)'

I am facing this problem for the first time and also I am new to this field. Can someone guide to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The doucmnentaion is a little confusing as it still shows the obsoleted methods, although in the detail it shows they are obsoleted but with no links to newer documentation (at this time).

It may be easiest to look at some of the examples available - for example this set includes examples using AddComponent to create a new Anchor: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/AnchorCreator.cs

```js
            // Note: the anchor can be anywhere in the scene hierarchy
            var gameObject = Instantiate(prefab, hit.pose.position, hit.pose.rotation);

            // Make sure the new GameObject has an ARAnchor component
            anchor = gameObject.GetComponent<ARAnchor>();
            if (anchor == null)
            {
                anchor = gameObject.AddComponent<ARAnchor>();
            }
```

More detail on ARFoundtaion here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/features

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mick, Should I enter these lines of code in the ARFoundationFacade.cs file or create a new .cs file with the code provided in the github?

Comment: You might actually find it easiest to start with a working sample and modify it as you need.

Comment: if you don't mind can you explain me step by step as of how to do this? I am really sorry, coz I am extremely inexperienced in this field

Comment: There are actually some set by step instructions available online in a codelab that will help you: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/arcore-unity-ar-foundation#0